# pictures and stargazer table in wrong position

Tags: floats, positioning

I am having problems with my overleaf document. I am trying to fit pictures and a stargazer table, but they appear in the wrong position.

My current code is as follows:

```
\begin{table}[!htbp]\centering 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lc} 
\tiny
(table here) 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table} 

\begin{center}[!htbp]
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{picture.png}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What do you mean with wrong position?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Environment center doesn't have positioning options. It is where is inserted in document. To see what is wrong at you, you must provide a small but complete document, which reproduce your problem.

Comment: the only purpose of the `table` environment is to allow the table to move, so if the first one moves that is by design.  `center` does not have an optional argument so presumably `\begin{center}[!htbp]` sets the text `[!htbp]` in the middle of the page. the picture will then be set following that.

Comment: Placing \floatbarrier between the image and the table did the job. A thousand thanks.